# Mirroring a mailing list in Google Groups?

Tags: google-groups, mailing-list

How can I mirror a mailing list powered by Mailman in Google Groups if I am not the moderator of this mailing list? Instead of reading it by mail I would like to read it in the Google Groups interface. The mailing list is currently open to read but only subscribers can post to it, which should map nicely to the "Public" setting of Google Groups.

I can set up a group, but how do I get the new messages from the mailing list in the Google Groups list? Is there a way to import the archives too?

**Edit:** I was able to set up a group via the setting Sathya told me about, but the `Reply-To` header is now set to *both* `my-group@googlegroups.com` and `the-original-group@example.com`, while it should only be the latter. I have the following options for *Replies to messages*:

> - Replies are sent to the whole group.
> - Replies are sent to the author of the message.
> - Replies are sent to the owners of the group.
> - Users decide where their replies are sent.

I don't think any of these will do what I want. Google should just send the mail to `the-original-group@example.com` and don't set the `Reply-To` header. Where can I change that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a group, from Group Settings -> Advanced - ensure `This group is hosted on another mailing list host` is checked and provide the email address of the mailing list.

Comment: That settings screen links to [the relevant help article](https://groups.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=46387). I have tried this and got a confirmation mail as the first message to the list. I clicked the confirmation link and deleted the message. I'll try to submit a new message to the list, if that works and other new messages arrive in the Google group, I'll accept this answer and award the bounty.

Comment: Sure, @JanFabry

Comment: Sending and receiving works, thank you. You will get your bounty when I can award it, which is 17 hours from now.

Comment: Glad to help, @JanFabry

Comment: One annoying issue: the `Reply-To` header [is set to both the Google groups and the mailing list address](https://groups.google.com/group/wp-docs/msg/7aafbfb28001c6fd?dmode=source&output=gplain&noredirect), so people trying to reply to my posts get an error because their direct message to Google groups will not be accepted. On other mailing list mirrors [this does not happen](https://groups.google.com/group/wp-hackers/msg/8821ef96b64a508a?dmode=source&output=gplain&noredirect). None of the four options for *"Replies to messages"* seem to match my case.

Comment: This option no longer seems to exist.

Comment: no more this option!